# Clean install of Ubuntu 12.10 not booting

Tags: installation, 12.10

Just installed Ubuntu 12.10 (wasn't 100% happy with 13.04 yet) from a USB drive.  I have done this numerous times.  This time I did the install three times.  I think something was wrong with one flash drive, and the installation hung, so I reinstalled WUBI onto another USB drive and did this install again (wiping everything out each time).  After this install, the computer doesn't boot, and all I get is a black screen with blinking cursor.  So I did another fresh install thinking something strange happened, but in the end I got the same result.  I have a Dell Vostro A90 with a runcore 32GB SSD and 2GB ram.  I have been using Ubuntu full time on this computer since 11.04 and figured it was time for a clean start.  I'm going home to play with it some, but if anyone has any ideas, I'm obviously not making a lot of progress here.

Comment: How are installing?  What option are you choosing at the Installation Type Scree? Do you have Windows installed?

Comment: Don't have another OS.  I've tried directly installing as well as "try ubuntu" and installing from the USB desktop as others have suggested.  Erase and install 12.10 over anything else.  No special partitioning.  Even pulled the SSD out last night and gave it a long hard format before one last attempt and still it doesn't work.  Just re-downloaded the iso in case that's the issue.

Comment: Running install of 12.10 with fresh download of iso.  Just made another USB with a 12.04 iso I have successfully used previously.  If it doesn't work this time, I'll try installing 12.04 and upgrading from there.

Comment: So that last install also failed.  Going with 12.04 this time.

Comment: I should add, it doesn't look as though the installs are actually failing.  If I boot from USB and inspect the contents of the SSD, everything looks in order.  Perhaps a problem with the boot sequence?

Comment: 12.04 install went perfectly.  Given my experience, I'd say there is a problem with the current 12.10 iso?

Answer (score 0):

Install BootRepair on a live usb.  It might be able to quickly and easily fix your problem.